# Java SE. Метод main. Как передать в параметрах main() имена файлов?

Tags: java

Есть задание - небольшая программа на Java. Одно из условий:запуск приложения через `public static void main(String[] args)`, `args[]`  параметра: файл входных данных, файл для записи ответа.

Не могу сообразить, как в `args[]` передать имена файлов:

```
input.txt, jutput.txt.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если можно - на примере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запуск через main означает запуск из командной строки.
Параметры передаются после, собственно, названия файла, который запускаешь.

```
java -jar myjar.jar input.txt output.txt
```

Потом в main эти параметры получаешь

```
String fileNameIn = args[0];
String fileNameOut = args[1];
```

Comment: Еще вопрос, если можно: если работаю в среде разработки IntelliJIdea, и в свойствах проекта указываю эти имена файлов (меню Run -> Edit Configuration -> в поле Program Arguments) - ИДЕЯ их не видит, видит только с полными путями. Файлы лежат в корне папки с проектом. Что поправить, чтобы Идея видела файлы просто по имени?

Comment: @Miller777, возможно ты при запуске не выбираешь нужную конфигурацию? У меня нормально открывает файлы из корня проекта. Но это на дебиане.

Comment: Не то, чтобы разобрался, но задача решена. Сделал jar, запускаю из командной строки так, как Вы сказали выше - все работает и только с именами, и с полными путями. В ИДЕЕ - только с полными. Спасибо!